# Border Over flow and Collapsible shown until click to hide

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 3 issues that are related to each other:

1. The background color of the border over flow to the second border, how can I make the space between the first and second border white.
2. When I minimize the page, the background color does not expand to cover all the text boxes and same thing with the border, how do i make the border and back ground color covers all content after minimizing. I tried overflow: hidden and scroll. scroll does what i want but the scroll bar should be made by browser not inside the border class.
3. How do i set collapse to show until clicked then it becomes hidden instead of hidden until clicked.
   I appreciate any help. You can run the code to see what i mean.

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Change 960 to desired width */
.border {
  border-style: double;
  border-width: 10px;
  background-color: silver;
  overflow: expand;
}

.collapsible {
  background-color: sliver;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.active,
.collapsible:hover {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.collapsible:after {
  content: "\002B";
  background-color: sliver;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.content {
  background-color: sliver;
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap  /3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="border">
    <button class="collapsible" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">
      Simple collapsible
    </button>
    <div id="demo" class="collapse">
      <div class="row" style="white-space:nowrap;">
        <br />
        <label style="margin-right:78px; margin-left:15px">Assign Date</label>
        <label style="margin-right:78px;">Task Subject</label>
        <label style="margin-right:78px;">Assigner</label>
        <label style="margin-right:78px;">Pirorty</label>
        <label style="margin-right:78px;">Status</label>
        <label style="margin-right:78px;">Category</label>
        <label style="margin-right:78px;">Due Date</label>
        <label style="margin-right:78px;">Complete</label>
      </div>
      <div class="row" style="white-space:nowrap;">
        <input
          type="text"
          name="AssignDate"
          style="width:80px; margin-right:78px; margin-left:15px"
        />

        <input
          type="text"
          name="TaskSubject"
          style="margin-right:78px; width:85px"
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          name="Assigner"
          style="margin-right:50px; width:85px"
        />

        <select name="Pirorty" style="width: 60px; margin-right:70px">
          <option>High </option>
          <option>Low</option>
          <option>Normal</option>
        </select>

        <select name="Status" style="width: 100px; margin-right:20px">
          <option>I</option>
          <option>N</option>
          <option>R</option>
          <option>Re</option>
          <option>Cancelled</option>
          <option>Closed</option>
        </select>

        <select name="Category" style="width: 100px; margin-right:40px">
          <option>A</option>
          <option>D</option>
          <option>E</option>
          <option>INFO</option>
          <option>I</option>
          <option>M</option>
          <option>N</option>
          <option>R</option>
          <option>S</option>
        </select>

        <input
          type="date"
          name="DueDate"
          style="width: 80px; margin-right:60px"
        />

        <select name="Category" style="width: 50px">
          <option>10</option>
          <option>20</option>
          <option>30</option>
          <option>40</option>
          <option>50</option>
          <option>60</option>
          <option>70</option>
          <option>80</option>
          <option>90</option>
          <option>100</option>
        </select>

        <br />
        <br />
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="IncludeTasksIWasCcedOn"
          style="margin-left:15px"
        />&nbsp;Include Tasks I was CC'd On&nbsp;
        <button type="submit" style="float :right; margin-right:15px">
          Filter
        </button>
        <button type="reset" style="float :right; margin-right:15px">
          Clear
        </button>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jsfiddle of collapse](https://jsfiddle.net/wbc1e9oh/)

4) sliver is not a valid color for css.

3) you need to add the class 'in' to element #demo for it to start expanded

2) you need to add

```
#demo {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

to your styles area. this will hide any children that would overflow an elements height when less than its children

1) the reason the bg color is in between is because you set the background color of the parent element. its bg color will flow into children unless overridden.
I set the parent bg to white and the children bg color set to silver.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta
    name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"
>
<link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
 </script>
     <style>
        .wrapper {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 100%;
        }

    /* Change 960 to desired width */
    .border {
        border-style: double;
        border-width: 10px;
        /* changed bg color */
        background-color: white;
        /* expand is not a valid value
        overflow: expand; */

    }

    .collapsible {
        /* sliver is not a valid color */
        background-color: sliver;
        color: black;
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 100%;
        border: none;
        text-align: left;
        outline: none;
        font-size: 15px;
    }

    .active,
    .collapsible:hover {
        background-color: lightgray;
    }

    .collapsible:after {
        content: '\002B';
        background-color: sliver;
        font-weight: bold;
        float: right;
        margin-left: 5px;
    }

    .active:after {
        content: "\2212";
    }

    .content {
        background-color: sliver;
        padding: 0 18px;
        max-height: 0;
        transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    }

    #demo {
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    /* added bg color here for inner area */
    #demo .row {
        background-color: silver;
    }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="border">
        <button
            class="collapsible"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#demo"
        >Simple collapsible</button>
        <div
            id="demo"
            class="collapse in"
        >
            <div style="clear:both;">
                <div
                    class="row"
                    style="white-space:nowrap;"
                >
                    <br />
                    <label style="margin-right:78px; margin-left:15px">Assign Date</label>
                    <label style="margin-right:78px;">Task Subject</label>
                    <label style="margin-right:78px;">Assigner</label>
                    <label style="margin-right:78px;">Pirorty</label>
                    <label style="margin-right:78px;">Status</label>
                    <label style="margin-right:78px;">Category</label>
                    <label style="margin-right:78px;">Due Date</label>
                    <label style="margin-right:78px;">Complete</label>
                </div>
                <div
                    class="row"
                    style="white-space:nowrap;"
                >
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        name="AssignDate"
                        style="width:80px; margin-right:78px; margin-left:15px"
                    />

                    <input
                        type="text"
                        name="TaskSubject"
                        style="margin-right:78px; width:85px"
                    />
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        name="Assigner"
                        style="margin-right:50px; width:85px"
                    />

                    <select
                        name="Pirorty"
                        style="width: 60px; margin-right:70px"
                    >
                        <option>High </option>
                        <option>Low</option>
                        <option>Normal</option>
                    </select>

                    <select
                        name="Status"
                        style="width: 100px; margin-right:20px"
                    >
                        <option>I</option>
                        <option>N</option>
                        <option>R</option>
                        <option>Re</option>
                        <option>Cancelled</option>
                        <option>Closed</option>
                    </select>

                    <select
                        name="Category"
                        style="width: 100px; margin-right:40px"
                    >
                        <option>A</option>
                        <option>D</option>
                        <option>E</option>
                        <option>INFO</option>
                        <option>I</option>
                        <option>M</option>
                        <option>N</option>
                        <option>R</option>
                        <option>S</option>
                    </select>

                    <input
                        type="date"
                        name="DueDate"
                        style="width: 80px; margin-right:60px"
                    />

                    <select
                        name="Category"
                        style="width: 50px"
                    >
                        <option>10</option>
                        <option>20</option>
                        <option>30</option>
                        <option>40</option>
                        <option>50</option>
                        <option>60</option>
                        <option>70</option>
                        <option>80</option>
                        <option>90</option>
                        <option>100</option>
                    </select>

                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        name="IncludeTasksIWasCcedOn"
                        style="margin-left:15px"
                    >&nbsp;Include Tasks I was CC'd On&nbsp;
                    <button
                        type="submit"
                        style="float :right; margin-right:15px"
                    >Filter</button>
                    <button
                        type="reset"
                        style="float :right; margin-right:15px"
                    >Clear</button>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you, very much. However, the overflow hidden, hides the text boxes when minimizing. Now I have another issue, this works with html but for some reason it doesn't work on razor view mvc5. i think it is jq issue.

Comment: Best option would be start a new question regarding the razor view mvc5 issue. So when you click minimize you want the inputs to be visible?what part of the ui do you want to hide on collapse?

Comment: If I minimize the browser everything inside the border should still show by scrolling right and left without setting overflow: scroll because that will make the scroll bar show inside the border. i want it to show at the bottom of the browser page. thank you.

Comment: add this to your style area:    .container {
   min-width: 1200px;
  }
this is the outer most container next to the body tag, so the scroll bar should be associated with this div

Comment: thank you. Everything is fixed. now i just need to figure out why it is not working on razor view. Hopefully someone reading the comments knows. Thanks again.

Comment: no problem, you should ask another question about razor. Add some .net and razor tags and it will have more visibility  than as a comment in this thread

Comment: I fixed by removing the JQ tags and <link> weird but fixed the issue now it works fine.